# Where's the current research at the intersection of labor market and macroeconomics?

Tags: macroeconomics, labor-economics, unemployment

I am into monetary economics and DSGE modeling, so I'm not very up-to-date when it comes to research on labor markets. Can anyone give me an overview of the current research trends on labor markets (ideally intersecting macroeconomics), if possible referencing recent papers/working papers or academics?